# Proper convention for blocks of code in Java

Tags: java, convention

I may be stupid for asking this but...  I don't know if I should format blocks like this:

```
public void elbow() {
    System.out.println("Elbow");
}
```

or:

```
public void elbow() {

    System.out.println("Elbow");

}
```

or are both correct?

Comment: This is mostly a matter of personal/team/company preference. e.g. the [Google Java Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.6.1-vertical-whitespace) says that intra-method whitespace should be used to create logical groupings of statements only. Personally, I think that you're just reducing the amount of code you can see on your screen with the second method.

Comment: both are correct but as per as i think first one look better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. It is a matter of preference. Most guys I work with like to be able to see more code on a single screen so opt for the first, within reason.

You may also mix them if you have a long loop it may be good to place whitespace at your own discretion to improve readability.